# How do I find all paths from sources to sinks in a directed graph?

Tags: perl, graph-theory

[image]

I want to find all paths from sources to sinks. Expected:

```
(3 11 17 24 32 39 45)
(3 11 18 26 33 39 45)
(3 11 18 26 33 40 46)
(3 11 18 26 33 40 47)
(3 11 19 27 33 39 45)
(3 11 19 27 33 40 46)
(3 11 19 27 33 40 47)
(3 11 19 27 34 40 46)
(3 11 19 27 34 40 47)
(6 12 20 27 33 39 45)
(6 12 20 27 33 40 46)
(6 12 20 27 33 40 47)
(6 12 20 27 34 40 46)
(6 12 20 27 34 40 47)
```

In my code, I know how to visit each vertex, but how do I properly remember and assemble the full paths?

```
use 5.028;
use feature 'signatures';
use strictures;
use Graph qw();

my $g = Graph->new(directed => 1);
for my $edge_tuple (qw(
    3-11 6-12 11-17 11-18 11-19 12-20 17-24 18-26 19-27 20-27 24-32 26-33
    27-33 27-34 32-39 33-39 33-40 34-40 39-45 40-46 40-47
)) {
    my ($from, $to) = split '-', $edge_tuple;
    $g->add_edge($from, $to);
}
say join ';', $g->source_vertices;
say join ';', $g->sink_vertices;

sub visit($g, $v, $p) {
    push @$p, $v;
    if ($g->is_sink_vertex($v)) {
        return;
    } else {
        for my $s ($g->successors($v)) {
            visit($g, $s, $p)
        }
    }
}

my $p = [];
for my $v ($g->source_vertices) {
    visit($g, $v, $p);
}
use Data::Dumper; say Dumper $p;
```

Comment: I don't know perl particularly well, but don't you already have the path in `$p`? Before your return statement in `visit` (`if ($g->is_sink_vertex($v)) { return; }`), you should be able to simply add `$p` to a global variable which then holds all paths.

Comment: You also might want to look at https://metacpan.org/pod/GraphViz2::Marpa::PathUtils

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I modified your code to pass a partial path into `visit()` and also to have `visit()` return all possible complete paths from the supplied partial path:

```
sub visit($g, $path) {
    my $v = $path->[-1];
    if ($g->is_sink_vertex($v)) {
        return $path;
    } else {
        my @more;
        for my $s ($g->successors($v)) {
            push @more, visit($g, [ @$path, $s ])
        }
        return @more;
    }
}

my @p;
for my $v ($g->source_vertices) {
    push @p, visit($g, [$v]);
}
use Data::Dumper; say Dumper @p;
```

The loops could then be reduced using map:

```
sub visit($g, $path) {
    my $v = $path->[-1];
    if ($g->is_sink_vertex($v)) {
        return $path;
    } else {
        return map { visit($g, [ @$path, $_ ]) } $g->successors($v);
    }
}

my @p = map { visit($g, [$_]) } $g->source_vertices;
```